# Schedule Jenkins job at specific startTimes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-cli

If we have the startTimes of the events when the Jenkins job needs to be triggered ; is it feasible to schedule the Jenkins job for the specific startTimes ?

Comment: Is your question about scheduling some job at a time well-known in advance, or is it about scheduling some job at a programmatically calculated time?

Comment: Well known time in advance actually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, some use jenkins to run maintenance jobs ( especially workflows ). You can set alerts on slack or email about the success/failure of the job, setup conditional triggers and set manual approvers for extra actions based on the result of a stage.

With great power comes great responsibilities and security issues so follow the best practices to avoid problems.

In the job configuration:

[image: job config]

Comment: But the above build trigger allows periodic schedules only and not non-periodic intervals.. right ? 
Is it possible like say to feed it with comma separated instances of start times then that should work.

Comment: It is possible to use comma separated lists and intervals. Click on the "?" blue button at the right of the box and you will get very a detailed explanation .